# Why is my exported function call returning undefined in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, return, undefined

I'm creating this webapp that will eventually pull live JSON objects from a website, filter them based on some values like name or ID, then push them to a list for rendering. While I have a decent Java background, I'm still very new to React, and rusty in terms of JS and HTML/CSS. I've been following tutorials and looking at related questions on this site in order to set this up; so I apologize if there are any rookie errors!

I've created this Filter class here:

```
class Filter {

id;
filterName;
isChecked;

constructor(id, filterName, isChecked) {
    this.id = id;
    this.filterName = filterName;
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
}

setupFilters() {
    var filters = []
    filters.push(new Filter("ACT_CLEAN", "Cleaning", false));
    filters.push(new Filter("ACT_WOODCUT", "Chop Wood", false));
    filters.push(new Filter("ACT_RUN", "Running", false));
    filters.push(new Filter("ACT_EAT", "Eat a Meal", false));
    filters.push(new Filter("ACT_IDLE", "Idle", false));

    return filters;
}

getFilterID() {
    return this.id;
}

getFilterName() {
    return this.filterName;
}

setChecked(bool) {
    this.isChecked = bool;
}

getChecked() {
    return this.isChecked;
}

getCheckedFilters() {
    var checkedFilters = []
    for (var i = 0; i < this.filters.length; i++) {
        if (this.filters[i].getChecked() == true) {
            checkedFilters.push(this.filters[i]);
        }
    }
    return checkedFilters;
}

}

export default Filter
export function getCheckedFilters(){}
export function setChecked(){}
export function getChecked(){}
export function getFilterId(){}
export function getFilterName(){}
export function setupFilters(){}
```

Which handles all information about a filter, including setting up the initial list of filters with setupFilters(), which is the subject of my question.

After exporting the setupFilters() function, I went over to my TaskList component and added the logic for rendering the list given active filters, as well as set a filter to true for some testing.

TaskList component:

```
class TaskList extends Component {

state = {
    tasks: [],
    loading: false
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        loading: true
    })
    var activeFilters = setupFilters();
    activeFilters[0].setChecked(true);
    console.log("Filters: " + activeFilters);
    axios.get(taskUrl)
        .then((res) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < activeFilters.length; i++) {
                if (activeFilters[i].id == res.data && activeFilters[i].getChecked == true) {
                    this.setState({
                        tasks: res.data,
                        loading: false
                    })
                }
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}



render() {
    const { tasks } = this.state
    if (tasks.length === 0) {
        return <p>No Tasks to Show.</p>
    }

    return (
        <ListGroup>
            {tasks.map(t => <TaskItem key={t.id} task={t} />)}
        </ListGroup>
    )
}
}

export default TaskList
```

However, and this is where my issue comes in... this function returns nothing, undefined. I check it within the scope of this component and it went from a function that would return filter[] to an alias function that was void. Did I export the function incorrectly in the Filter class? Should I call the function differently in a component versus another class or something else? I would appreciate any and all feedback on why this rather simple function doesn't return anything.

Comment: You don't need to export the methods of a class individually, you can just export the class and then call the methods on an instance of the class instead of calling them directly like functions.

Comment: I attempted to implement this, and it doesn't quite work in this fashion, either. It returns [Object Object] instead of undefined, which is a step in the right direction for sure.